# PhD Supervisor not answering any emails

Tags: advisor, supervision

I am an accepted PhD student with funding and thesis based supervised by a professor.

For 2 weeks my supervisor has not answered emails I have sent and I have sent the same one 3 times in the last 2 weeks.

My questions and concerns are time sensitive and require their input, advice and approval this week - in a few days - as there are hard university deadlines.

No communication has been established and no indication about the lack of response ever since my acceptance.

What should I do ?  We are online so I cant really call or drop by the office.

I have even copied the department administrative staff as they suggested to speed up his response.  That also did not work.

Comment: Is it possible that your supervisor has been unable to communicate (due to being on vacation, traveling, or being ill for example)?  Does your supervisor have an administrative assistant that you could contact?

Comment: If there is no assistant or secretary, you should contact whoever is in charge of enforcing the hard deadlines and discuss your issue with them.

Comment: He is not ill, no one is sick in his family and he is not on vacation.  He is just not answering his emails.  I will end up talking to the people enforcing the deadlines and work it out with them.  Then will just tell me they need his input and maybe they can force his hand.  Ugh.  Why is this, this way ?

Comment: How do you know that he or any of his family members is not ill if you cannot communicate with him? That seems like a bold statement to me. You seem to assume malice. Instead just calm down. Don't make any assumptions. Calmly talk to the people enforcing the deadline, and state just the facts: you emailed, he did not anser, you don't know why.

Comment: Probably the office requiring the administrative work can contact the supervisor. It might be university dependent, but s/he will be the supervisor. I guess that most of the work required from you is based on a reasonable subdivision of tasks. But as it seems impossible right now, perhaps they should work with the supervisor and you in parallel. Carbon copy might be the way.